# docker volumes and apache permissions

Tags: php, apache, docker, permissions

I'm using docker for serving huge website with php. Issue is that when I'm linking my host volume to container I get permission errors. I know that I could run `chmod -R 777 /var/www` but isn't it little bit dangerous?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0.3-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y sendmail libpng-dev

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

My Docker-Compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./test.com:/var/www/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: test
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
```

Any ideas how to handle host volume permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I spent sometime looking for the best solution for this case.
The cleanest way I found was setting the permission to the user 33 at the host machine.

Options I've tried:

1. **Define a different user ID in Docker composer file**: May work many times, but may cause errors when Apache trying to use internal files (e.g. ssh keys)
2. **Passing the local UID as an env variable and adding www-data to the same group/id**: You must do that during the building process as part of the Docker file instructions, so it also creates another sketchy scenario when you create a image with permissions from your host machine.

The less messy way I found is giving permissions to your local files to the user 33. Note that you do not have to create the user.

**setfacl -R -m u:33:rwx /path/to/your/files**

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely **not** a good idea to `chmod` with `777`, as you already suspected. You will need to chown the folders and files to the apache group with: `chown -R <current_user>:www-data /test.com` and change the permissions to `755`.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can set uid for docker container's user is equal with host user's uid. It should help.

Comment: Can you give an example? My host users name is docker. Do I need to add user docker to container and give the rights for folder.

Comment: You can get PUID and GUID by commands `id -u` and `id -g`. And you can create user inside container by Dockerfile, something like that:

`ARG PUID=1000`  `ARG PGID=1001`
`RUN groupadd -g $PGID customgrpoup && useradd -u $PUID -g customgrpoup -m customuser`

And now you should start services inside container by your new customuser.
Also you can pass PUID and GUID via docker-compose file as environment args.

If you do it, host user and docker user will be identical for filesystem.